# NullPointerException when accessing OutputStream from DiskLruCache

Tags: java, android, caching

I am using `DiskLruCache` to cache urls of images. I download an image using `AsyncTask` like so:

```
new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

        String path = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Get the assets from DiskLruCache
            try {
                if (url != null)
                    path = assetManager.getAssetFilePath(url);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                callback.downloadFailed();
            }

            return path;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            if (path != null)
                callback.assetDownloaded(path);
            else
                callback.downloadFailed();
        }

    }.execute();
```

`AssetManager` is a custom helper class that calls a method `getAssetFilePath(...)`. The exception occurs here in in this piece of code:

```
    DiskLruCache.Snapshot snapshot = mDiskCache.get(key);
    if (snapshot == null) {

        DiskLruCache.Editor editor = mDiskCache.edit(key);

        InputStream is = downloadFile(url);

        if (is == null) return null;

        // EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
        OutputStream os = editor.newOutputStream(0);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 10];
        int len;
        while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();

        editor.commit();
    }
```

Specifically this line here causes the exception:

```
OutputStream os = editor.newOutputStream(0);
```

I can't seem to duplicate this issue on any of my test devices but it is occurring for other users.

What is the cause of this issue and how can I go about tackling it?

The logcat is telling me:

> Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.OutputStream com.jakewharton.disklrucache.DiskLruCache$Editor.newOutputStream(int)' on a null object reference

Is there a better way to do this?

Also is this a good way to initialize `DiskLruCache`? If not then what is a good scalable initialization? Looking for best practices and implementations.

```
public CacheManager() {

    BASE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/exampleapp";

    try {
        mDiskCache = DiskLruCache.open(new File(BASE_PATH), VERSION, 1, CACHE_SIZE);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Asset Manager IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
    DiskLruCache.Editor editor = mDiskCache.edit(key);
```

Is already null - but you don't check for that. As `mDiskCache.get(key)` already returned null before this seems reasonable to check?

Comment: How can I prevent that? Is this normal behavior?

Comment: Is there a better way to handle this? A better architecture?

Comment: first just check for null and do nothing - the null might jndicate another edit is active (download in another thread). If the same image was read by multiple threads, you would see this error sometimes, but not always.

Comment: Then can you not instantiate another `Editor` in a separate thread? Seems a little problematic that you can only have one instance of `Editor` running. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can only have one **for that key** = for the one file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://jakewharton.github.io/DiskLruCache/com/jakewharton/disklrucache/DiskLruCache.html):

```
edit(String key): Returns an editor for the entry named key, or null if another edit is in progress.
```

You should check that it is not returning `null`, and if it is, try again at a future time when no other edits are in progress. (Perhaps queue the edit on a different thread).

Comment: Where can I find a good implementation of this? I can't seem to find good examples. I understand that probably using a priority queue is ideal here, but I have not working as much with caching before.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same Editor in different threads gives this error. Just make sure you synchronize the method that you are using Editor.

```
public synchronized writeMyDataToCache(String key, String data){
    DiskLruCache.Editor editor = diskLruCache.edit(key);
    writeSomethingToCache(editor, data);
}
```